# Server date and time delayed in Windows App

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

Hi i have a problem on getting the server date and time, i was able to get the date and time but in windows app form , when the form is open for long hours, the time will have a seconds delay (e.g 10 to 30 seconds) and also minutes if the application is open the whole day.

i used the code from this blog:

[Get database server date and time](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20837/Get-Database-Server-Date-and-Time)

How can i do this without delay greater than 10 seconds.

Any help would much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I think there will always be a delay because of different factors, best example is network connection speed. For what purpose are you gonna need it?

Comment: @CrushSundae , i agree with that , but if the form opens for long hrs it becomes minutes deelayed , it can affect because i am using the server time displayed in the form.. i use that in very important transactions and validations.

Comment: Just a theory, it might be slowing down because of the continuous calls you are passing to the server every second.

Comment: Sounds like you need to synch/check both the PC time and the server time to the "real" time. The server side should already do this but make sure. You can add code to your client to make sure the local PC is within limits. You could check the "real" time during transaction processing to make sure someone hasn't messed with the PC clock - or only use the real time as the transaction time regardless of what the PC time is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're assuming your timer fire exactly on 1 second intervals. It wont, the timers are not that accurate and you're seeing the results of this. The more busy your machine is the worse the problem will become.

Instead you need to use the current time on your computer as the increment.

1. When your application starts, use the code from the link to fetch the server time.
2. Find out the time difference and store this as a member variable.

   ```
   mDiff = serverTime - Now
   ```
3. Start a 1 second timer and display the new offset time

   ```
   dim time = Now + mDiff
   MyLabel.Text = time.ToString()
   ```

Comment: Ah you mean the increment will be getting on the clients pc time ?

Comment: is it reliable to use the client's PC time?

Comment: @CrushSundae nope! .. that's the problem , the reason why i use server date and time is to avoid the user from bypassing validations , because clients pc time can be editable.. thats why i ask FloatingKiwi if i understand him correctly for what he means of "current time of your computer".

Comment: The client PCs time is very stable. The way you're accessing it is not. Instead of incrementing by 1000ms you need to increment by the exact amount of time that has elapsed since the last timer which isn't exactly 1000ms

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it yet, just an idea.:

I used two **timer** controls here.

`Timer1` with an interval of `1 sec.` and `Timer2` with an interval of `10 secs.`

```
    Dim tempDateTime As DateTime = Now
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        tempDateTime = tempDateTime.AddSeconds(1)
        Label1.Text = tempDateTime
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
         Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

         rs = dbConn.Execute("SELECT GetDate() as CurrDateTime")
         tempDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(rs.Fields("CurrDateTime").Value)

         Label1.Text = tempDateTime 
    End Sub
```

I just used `Now` for the `tempDateTime` to have a temporary value (for atleast 1 sec.).

The idea here is:

It will now continue to run even though you are waiting for another call to the server to refresh time. Thus, making the timer to *still* run while waiting for another call on the server. After the new call, tempDateTime will now be set to the current server time, then Timer1 will make it run again, It's like *faking* that there is no delay in retrieving the server time.

Comment: Actually same thing that comes on my mind while waiting for the easiest way and good answer :) , i am trying to code it using two timers , once is for refreshing the label every 15 secs , if i succeeded i will mark yours as answer :)

Comment: Hahaha .. pinoy ka pala :/ pinahirapan mo pa ko mag english ^^, .. i am creating new class for timer2.. hope this works ^^, you'll see if i'm done.

Comment: Hehe. Just a guess based on how you named your account.

Comment: Btw, I tested it. It's working fine in my computer with a _networked_ database.

Comment: Sundae i'm having trouble , i was able to refresh but after refresh it turns back to delayed time, Maybe i'm missing something, can you show me your code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122265/discussion-between-crush-sundae-and-japongskie).